# MacBook Pro - how do I stop DVD player from autoplaying?

Tags: macos, macbook, macbook-pro, optical-drive

I've tried the following to disable this behaviour:

- `System Preferences` -> `CDs & DVDs` -> `When you insert a video DVD`: set to `Ignore` (actually moved all of them to `Ignore`)

Neither of these made a difference; insert the disc and the DVD player still starts playing it. Any other options? I just need to hide DVD player from the Desktop and stop autoplay.

Comment: Nothing is easy. DVD Player has its own preferences related to autoplay.

Comment: @Mockman - DVD Player is one of the few apps that has no preferences menu item at all.

Comment: @Tetsujin I guess things have changed. I'm using Sierra. Thanks for the head's up.

Comment: @Mockman - I guess it depends what OS the OP is on, which they didn't tell us. The last Mac to have an optical drive can technically use Catalina, which would preclude use of RCDefaultApp from my answer below. Anything earlier can be controlled by it though. I'm not sure when the Prefs moved - probably the same time the App itself vanished from Apps & was hidden deep in Core Services instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're still on Mojave or earlier, try [RCDefaultApp](https://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/) which has a few more options you can set to ignore. It won't run on anything newer than Mojave & its modern replacement SwiftDefaultApp has no options for optical drives.